# high temp hard disk with Home partition on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, ubuntu-20.04

I just got an ssd for my laptop and I have a 1TB hard drive next to it
After installing Windows, I installed Ubuntu 20.04 next to Windows by creating the root and efi partitions in ssd and creating the home partition in the amount that I had separated from hdd, but after entering Ubuntu, after a short time, I feel its hard disk temperature It goes up for no reason (this problem does not exist in Windows 10). Has anyone ever had this problem? If you have a solution, thank you for your help.
The format of home and root partitions is ext4 and I do not have a file inside the home partition, if I need to change its format, it is not a problem.

Comment: If you can touch it and it doesn't hurt, it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

By hot, you mean how hot? My laptop HDD is 10 degree celsius hotter than my room, and it's spinning in 5400 RPM (I guess). It is supposed to be hot. You boot and use Windows 10 from SSD and that doesn't use the HDD (until you start using drives on HDD). When you boot Ubuntu, it spins the HDD immidietly, write stuff and things get hot. HDDs are hot compared to SSDs. They are electro-mechanical (electro-magneto-mechanical, in proper), thus have moving parts, generates more heat. Also they needs more power and subsequently more heat. Also much write may cause heating. You can monitor the temperature with `hddtemp` or Gnome Disks and check whose writing with `iotop`. In Windows, you may use [Open Hardware Monitor](https://openhardwaremonitor.org/) to check the temperature. Hope this helps.